# Unresolved class problem AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, kotlin

[This is the AndroidManifest.xml code]. The muse_transition_rhythm works, but the other two have errors:

```
`android:name=".activities.Muse.muse_transition_rhythm"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.categories.CategoriesActivity" />

       <activity
            android:name=".activities.Muse.muse_pick"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Muse.museHome"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.Welcome" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".activities.SpeechService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

In museHome.kt, I am trying to open a new activity(muse_pick) with the click of button3, but it is not working.......

```
 `fun onCreate() {
        setContentView(R.layout.muse_home)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val Intent = Intent(this, muse_pick_duration::class.java)
            startActivity(Intent)
        }
    }
}`
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[muse_pick.kt]:

```
  `package com.tammy.tammyapp.activities.Muse
    
    import com.tammy.tammyapp.R
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import com.tammy.tammyapp.activities.TutorialActivity
    
    abstract class muse_pick_duration : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.muse_pick_duration)
    
        }
    }`
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
muse_home.xml has button 3:

```
 // button 3
    `<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="508dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="237dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="266dp"
        android:text="Welcome to MUSE,"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />`
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I keep getting an error that my classes are unresolved even though I included them in my AndroidManifest.xml........... My button3 is also not opening a new activity even after adding the code that opens a new activity. Does anyone know why?

I tried invalidating the cache and restarting it. I also tried adding the path to each of the `.kt` files. Is there anything else I can do?

This is my directory(in case I'm missing something):
[image]

///////////////////////////////////////////////

Removing the abstract keyword fixed my problem, but I have the MipniHome(originally MuseHome) underlined in red but there are no errors....
[image]

[image]

Comment: try using muse_pick_duration instead of muse_pick

Answer (score 0):

In the file `muse_pick.kt`, you've declared

```
abstract class muse_pick_duration
```

This is why you are getting the error in the manifest, because it expects to find a class called `muse_pick`. Although Kotlin doesn't require the file name and class name to the same, this is causing confusion so you should fix it so the class name and file name are the same.

Also, when you try to launch the `Activity`, you are doing this:

```
val Intent = Intent(this, muse_pick_duration::class.java)
```

`muse_pick_duration` has been declared as `abstract` and you cannot instantiate an abstract class, so Android will not be able to launch this class. Remove the `abstract` keyword and ensure that the class name matches the actual name of the class.

---

I'm assuming that your file `museHome.kt` contains this:

```
fun onCreate() {
    setContentView(R.layout.muse_home)
    ...
```

This isn't correct. You need to override the `onCreate()` method with the correct signature, like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.muse_home)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, that removed the pick_duration error. But, museHome is still in red on AndroidManifest.... and the museHome.xml is underlined in red but there are no errors when I open the file...

Comment: What is the content of museHome.kt? Please edit your question and post that file.

Comment: Added more stuff to the answer, hopefully that solves your problem. You need to pay careful attention to what you are doing. Also, the IDE (Android Studio or whatever you are using) can help generate the correct code to override methods automatically, which helps prevent errors.

Comment: I do have the override though.... It still gives me the same error. Lemme try adding that to my original question so you can see

Comment: The 'override' is only part of the problem. The `Bundle` argument is also missing, this causes the signature mismatch.

Comment: I can't tell why you get the red underline on the XML layout file from what you've posted. However, please don't use mixed-case names in the layout files. Use all lowercase letters and the underscore character ONLY. That may be your problem.

Comment: changing all my file names to lowercase worked, thank You!